# HighCharts shows partially when exporing to image

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I'm trying to export HighCharts chart to image using `modules/exporting.js` downloaded image contains chart only partially. Setting different `widht`/`height`/`sourceWidth`/`sourceHeight` didn't solve the problem. Tried to insert my data to example jsfiddle - png downloaded normally.

What can cause this issue?

UPD:
This is settings of my chart

```
options: {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    height: 600
  },
  title: { text: '' },
  subtitle: { text: '' },
  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: { text: 'Percentage' },
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    minorTickInterval: 1,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 120,
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.tooltip}{series.name}: {point.y}%'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      turboThreshold: 0
    }
  },
  series: [ ],
  credits: { enabled: false },
  exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    chartOptions: {
      legend: { enabled: true },
      xAxis: [{ labels: { style: { fontSize: '5px' } } }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if the sample code provided it will be more clear what you have tried.

Comment: It's hard to say what could have an impact on it without the code example. Please try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @KrishnaKanth thanks for reply. I've just updated question with settings of my chart. I hope it will help.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for reply. I've just updated question with settings of my chart. I hope it will help.

Comment: @yar_resh it seems that your series array is empty - is it loaded dynamically somehow?